# How to say about Master's Degree

Tags: phrase-requests

I really need to know how to say that a person studies something in MA level. I need several phrases for this to have choices for various circumstances. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would you have more luck on the ELL site? You'd probably say post-graduate studies, or simply, "is doing an MA in the field" (such as "is doing an MA in Electrical Engineering").

Answer (score 1):

The two most common titles of master's degrees are Master of Arts, M.A., and Master of Science, M.S. Your sentence is quite broad, lacking enough clarity, so I'm not sure in what context you need to use these phrases, but you can always say:

> They are doing a Master's degree in Chemistry.
>
> They have received an M.A. degree in English literature.